# Output 2 columns with average from year t and year t+1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| playerid  | season  | Stat    |
|-----------|---------|---------|
| 1         | 2014    | 2.3     |
| 1         | 2015    | 1.4     |
| 1         | 2016    | 3.5     |
| 2         | 2011    | 1.5     |
| 2         | 2012    | 5.5     |
| 3         | 2010    | 6.7     |
| 3         | 2011    | 2.6     |
```

I want a table with 2 columns which average 'STAT' for year t in column 1 and year t+1 in column 2.

IE-Column 1 would have averages of 'Stat' for:

```
 playerid=1 & season=2014, 
 playerid=1 & season=2015, 
 playerid=2 & season=2011, 
 playerid=3 & season=2010.
```

Column 2 would have averages of 'Stat' for:

```
 playerid=1 & season=2015,
 playerid=1 & season=2016,
 playerid=2 & season=2012,
 playerid=3 & season=2011.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look up next year with a `left join`:

```
select  cur.playerid
,       cur.season
,       cur.stat as stat_this_season
,       next.stat as stat_next_season
from    YourTable cur
left join
        YourTable next
on      cur.playerid = next.playerid
        and cur.year = next.year - 1
```

To filter out seasons that do not have a next season, change the `left join` to an `inner join` (which you can abbreviate as `join`.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the analytic function ROW_NUMBER() to order the rows by year, for each player. Then you can get the requested averages by excluding the first record (for Column 1) and the last record (for Column 2). In case there is only one season, Stat will be included into Column 1 only.

```
SELECT t.playerid,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.ord1 != 1 OR
                     (t.ord1 = 1 AND t.ord2 = 1) THEN Stat END) AS Column_1,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.ord2 != 1 THEN Stat END) AS Column_2
  FROM (SELECT s.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playerid ORDER BY season DESC) AS ord1,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playerid ORDER BY season ASC) AS ord2
          FROM table_1 s) t
 GROUP BY playerid
 ORDER BY playerid
```

If you remove the GROUP BY from previous query, you will get only one row with both averages over all players:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN t.ord1 != 1 OR
                     (t.ord1 = 1 AND t.ord2 = 1) THEN Stat END) AS Column_1,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.ord2 != 1 THEN Stat END) AS Column_2
  FROM (SELECT s.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playerid ORDER BY season DESC) AS ord1,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playerid ORDER BY season ASC) AS ord2
          FROM table_1 s) t
```